# how to make android kotiln RecyclerView textview dynamic height

Tags: android, kotlin

i want dynamic RecyclerView but my RecyclerView is not dynamic If more than 3 lines of letters are over, the image is invisible and cut off, so I want a dynamic RecyclerView item.

this is my recyclerview item code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/linear_imageView"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linear_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linear_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

set height attribute `wrap_content` in root view container

Answer (score 1):

From Android Support Library 23.2.1 update, all WRAP_CONTENT should work correctly.

Please update version of a library in gradle file OR to further :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```